# R simple dplyr solution to filter

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need a simple dplyr solution to filter a data.frame. For example I have

```
set.seed(100)
x = sort(sample(1:5,10,1))
y = sort(sample(6:10,10,1))

z = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

z
```

```
   x y
1  1 6
2  2 7
3  2 7
4  2 8
5  2 8
6  3 8
7  3 9
8  4 9
9  4 9
10 5 9
```

As first, I need an output which extract the doubled values like this:

```
one = rbind(c(1,6),c(2,7), c(2,8), c(3,8), c(3,9), c(4,9), c(5,9))
one
```

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    2    8
[4,]    3    8
[5,]    3    9
[6,]    4    9
[7,]    5    9
```

```
two = rbind(c(1,6),c(2,7),c(3,8),c(4,9),c(5,9))
two
```

Then I want to have unique x with for example the first entry like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5    9
```

In a last step I need the number of different values of y in x:

```
three = rbind(c(1,1),c(2,2),c(3,2),c(4,2),c(5,1))
```

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    4    2
[5,]    5    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of these can be achieved using `distinct` and `group_by`. The first, group by both `x` and `y` and run `distinct` to get all unique combinations of `x` and `y`.

For the second, we group only by `x` and run `distinct` again.  We have to include `.keep_all` to make sure `y` stays in the resulting dataframe because it isn't contained in the `group_by`.  This works because `distinct` keeps the first occurring record for `x`.  To clarify check `?distinct`.

```
set.seed(100)
x = sort(sample(1:5,10,1))
y = sort(sample(6:10,10,1))

z = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# First scenario
z1 <- z %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  distinct(x)
```

z1 output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   x, y [7]
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     2     8
4     3     8
5     3     9
6     4     9
7     5     9
```

```
# Second scenario
z2 <- z %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  distinct(x, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

z2 output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   x [5]
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
4     4     9
5     5     9
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `distinct(z, x, y)`
2. `group_by(z, x) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()`
3. `group_by(z, x) %>% summarize(count = n())`

Comment: What do you get for `packageVersion(dplyr)`? The mechanics of `slice()` vary depending on package version.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can achieve this with the following code:

1. Get distinct x,y

```
z %>% distinct(.keep_all=TRUE)
```

2. Group by x, get row number per group and filter the first row with x,y

```
z %>% 
group_by(x) %>%
mutate(row=row_number()) %>%
filter(row==1) %>%
select(-row)
```

3. Group by x and count distinct y values

```
z %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(values=n_distinct(y,na.rm=TRUE))
```